# Open HTML email in browser but preventing loading of images and scripts

Tags: email, html

Email mail clients such as mu4e are not perfectly suited to view HTML emails.  I usually try to view it in Emacs (using Emacs' own HTML redinging enging shr) but revert to opening the email in a browser if it is not readable.  However, one problem with this approach is that the browser will load images, java scripts, and other remote resources references in the HTML potentially compromising my privacy.  The question is: how can I prevent remote resources from being loaded?

I considered to filter the HTML to remove java script and images but it turns out that there are so many different ways to load remote material that filtering is not feasible (CSS, Adobe Flash, ...).  So I think it would be better to open the HTML in a browser (tab?) that doesn't connect to the internet.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just an idea: Firefox offers "profiles". If you create one that is exclusively for viewing emails you could adjust preferences to your need?!

Comment: Maybe a silly idea, but easy to implement: make a Docker container with a browser of your choice (some info on how to run a GUI app in Docker container: http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/ ). You could then configure the container not to have network access.

Comment: Thanks both. @Matthias, I think that might be an ok solution.  In that profile, I could set the HTTP proxy to something that doesn't exist and that would hopefully prevent any remote connections.  I'll try it.

Comment: It's really not something i have done before, but there is an option called "Offline browsing" in the firefox profile manager (See here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_work-offline ). May be it helps further...